# Is it possible to schedule "Alarms Only" mode in Windows 10 using a shell script?

Tags: windows-10, shell-script, focus-assist

I want to automate this to trigger every day at certain intervals, it seems so hard to configure a good notification system in Windows 10.

I would like to trigger the Windows focus "Alarms only" mode at certain intervals throughout the day, is this possible?

[image: See Image]

Comment: Are you talking about Focus Assist?

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about Alarms only.

https://i.imgur.com/XG8xvLt.png

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer, please? Include that screenshot in the question.

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Comment: @Yedya did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

There's a PowerShell workaround which revolves around clicking menu entries:

> ```
> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
> [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("(^{ESC})")   
> Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500   
> [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("(Focus Assist)")   
> Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200   
> [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")   
> Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500  
> [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")  
> Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500     
> [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("(%{F4})")
> ```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/SQLDBAWithABeard/ab2dd8c60bb8453aac88d981eb8321c6). This basically opens Start menu, searches `Focus Assist`, opens settings for it, goes to proper field with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, marks the radio with <kbd>Space</kbd> and closes the window.

Of course it might not work if you're doing something else at that time and interrupt it, PowerShell is not the best tool for GUI automation.

Similar, more reliable script could be created with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), which could be combined with [`BlockInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/BlockInput.htm) to ensure proper execution and/or send keys to the proper window with [`ControlSend`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ControlSend.htm) or by clicking on specified GUI elements.

And alternatively you can automate <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> instead, which opens the actions center with a tile which can be switched to `Alarms only`.